# Prevent images in slider from being seen as the page loads?

Tags: css, wordpress

Here's the site:

http://cholakislaw.com/install/

I think it's a tweak I made to the CSS because the demo for the theme doesn't suffer from this issue:

http://www.mojo-themes.com/item/attorneys-lawyer-wordpress-theme/demo/

Comment: please post the code you think is causing the problem!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the images start to load before the slider component, easySlider in that case, has set `height` and `overflow` property of the `#slider` element. Thus, when the images start to load, `#slider` is high enough to see more than the first image.

To prevent this, you could add in `slider.css` the following rules :

```
#slider {
    height: 100%; /* parent element with class .slider has his height already set */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I knew it was something like this!  It worked!  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Best way to do is:

**CSS**

```
 .slider ul li img {
    display: none;
 }

 .slider ul li:first-child img{
     display: block;
 }
```

By doing this, you'll hide all slideshow images and then show only first-child on load. Later, js will do it's trick and overwrite it.

Comment: I've done what you suggested.  It doesn't appear to have an effect.

Comment: In your case it has to be `.slider ul li img`..check updated answer...

Comment: I've now tried .slider .image img {, still no.  What am I missing?

Comment: Still no. :/  Something strange going on here.